# Installing python module to Mac OS QGIS through console

Tags: python, macos, qgis

My QGIS python console returns error

```
import tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

I installed the python module to OS through pip but it is not available to QGIS python console. A previous question suggests it should have worked: [Installing the Python geojson module on Mac OS X Yosemite to use with QGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927172/installing-the-python-geojson-module-on-mac-os-x-yosemite-to-use-with-qgis)

Comment: What python are you using? Run `which pip` in your terminal.
What's your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip